# Opticon F31 can't enter VCP/Serial mode

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, serial-port, barcode-scanner

I've just purchased an Opticon F31 2D barcode scanner for use in a cocoa mac application as a USB Serial device.

We've used the NLV 2101 and scanned the C01 barcode from the universal manual which works, but the F31 always gives back a bad scan error and stays in HID mode (acts as a keyboard). Have I bought the correct scanner or is this one faulty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the command code to switch the scanner to VCP mode doesn't work on the F31. You need to use the barcodes on the following URL to switch between VCP and HID mode.

http://wiki.opticon.com/index.php/2D_Scanner_USB_Default